# unable to iterate on HtmlCollection

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, htmlcollection

I have an issue with a simple code

```
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
    var plop = Array.prototype.slice(x);
    console.log(x);
    console.log(x.length);
    console.log(plop);
```

output

```
[item: function, namedItem: function]
0: th.fc-day-header.fc-sun.fc-widget-header.fc-first
1: th.fc-day-header.fc-mon.fc-widget-header
2: th.fc-day-header.fc-tue.fc-widget-header
3: th.fc-day-header.fc-wed.fc-widget-header
4: th.fc-day-header.fc-thu.fc-widget-header
5: th.fc-day-header.fc-fri.fc-widget-header
6: th.fc-day-header.fc-sat.fc-widget-header.fc-last
length: 7__proto__: HTMLCollection
    controller.js:309 0
    controller.js:310 []
```

Why does I see lenght 7 here and the x.length gives 0 ?

Thanks in advance

update : I set the code in

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
}
```

And it works now. I'm not yet able to set an onclick method but it progress ^^

Comment: works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mJ3Jm4Eh34YnNYFh3Oss?p=preview

Comment: With your posted code, I would expect `x.length === 7` but `plop.length === 0`.  They way you're using `Array.prototype.slice` is incorrect.  You should do `Array.prototype.slice.call( x )` instead.  See: [Array.prototype.slice - Array-like objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like)

Comment: thx with your splice it works fine :)

Comment: Or `[].slice.call(x)` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
var arr =  Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
        console.log(arr);
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           // console.log("iterate");
            console.log(arr[i]);
            arr[i].onclick = function(){
                console.log("lol");
            };
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.call()` when you're trying to make an array copy from the `HTMLCollection`.  Instead of this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
var plop = Array.prototype.slice(x);
```

You can do this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
var plop = Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
console.log(plop);
```

---

Note: you don't need to make an array copy just to iterate over it.  You can iterate an HTMLCollection directly:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i]);
}
```

Comment: for(let i=0;i<len;i++){ console.log(tweets.item(i).innerText); }

Comment: @YashdeepHinge - In order for us to help you, we would need to see your specific code.  To do that, you should post your own question with your own code in it and describe exactly what error you observe.  Comments are not for asking questions about your own code.  Post your own question for that.

Comment: try running this code over the chrome dev console.

`var tweets=document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text");
for(var i=0;i<tweets.length;i++){ console.log(i); }`

on this link https://twitter.com/hqtriviascribe?lang=en

I wanted to extract the text inside the paragraph

Comment: @YashdeepHinge - Please post your own question.  It's not appropriate on stackoverflow to pose new questions about new situations in comments.  Then, people can provide you with actual answers to your specific situation.

Comment: Ohhh yeah your right I will post a question. Although I did completed the task with a different approach but I will ask this to know why is it not working the way its supposed to.